# Idea пишет, что значение, присваиваемое переменной, никогда не используется

Tags: java

В данном коде Idea мне сообщает, что `!chosen`  всегда имеет значение true, а в строке `chosen = true;` пишет, что значение true, присваиваемое переменной `chosen`, никогда не используется.

Я не понимаю. Ведь у меня есть boolean `chosen`, значение которого по умолчанию false. Я указываю выполнять цикл while, пока значение равно false, но при выборе того или иного if значение переменной должно меняться на true, и цикл завершается.

Пояснение: это случайный выбор одного из автоматических тестов. Место, где указано `!this.pkcs10created` - по умолчанию false. Метод выбора теста возвращает r - случайный - и уже в методе запуска теста `pkcs10created` меняется на true, но это же не должно мешать выходу из while, поскольку я явно указываю поменять chosen на true, а когда `chosen == true`, программа не должна вообще уже в цикл заходить.

```
 boolean chosen = false;
            SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
            while (!chosen) {
                int r = random.nextInt(13);
                if (r == 0 && !this.pkcs10created) {
                    chosen = true;
                    return r;
                }

                if (r == 1 && !this.certificateSet) {
                    chosen = true;
                    return r;
                }
                if (r == 2 && !this.signCreated) {
                    chosen = true;
                    return r;
                }
                if (r == 3 && !this.ocspCreated) {
                    chosen = true;
                    return r;
                }
                if (r == 4 && !this.tspCreated) {
                    chosen = true;
                    return r;
                }
                if (r == 5 && !this.ocspKvitCreated) {
                    chosen = true;
                    return r;
                }
                if (r == 6 && !this.tspKvitCreated) {
                    chosen = true;
                    return r;
                }
```

Comment: Наводящий вопрос - подскажите пожалуйста, что именно делает инструкция `return` ?

Comment: return возвращает порядковый номер теста, который надо выполнить.

Comment: Еще раз, вспомните что именно делает инструкция `return`, вообще в Java? (подсказка, она выходит из метода). И теперь подумайте, какой смысл присваивать `chosen = true` перед выходом из метода?

Comment: ну да, логично, что-то не подумал об этом)

Comment: А теперь прикиньте, что если все `chosen = true` лишние, то и проверка `while (!chosen)` тоже лишена смысла, т.к. `chosen` всегда остается `false`.

Comment: В яве нет брэйк?

Answer (score 1):

У Вас `chosen` является лишним, так как после установки его в `true` возвращается результат из Вашего метода.

Можете убрать chosen и изменить на

```
while true { ...
```

---

Либо можете переписать чтобы переменная `chosen` была необходима и была только одна точка выхода:

```
boolean chosen = false;
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
int r;
while (!chosen) {
    r = random.nextInt(13);
    if ((r == 0 && !this.pkcs10created) || <остальные условия>) {
        chosen = true;
    }
}
return r;
```